# Retrofit: passing multiple GET parameter

Tags: android, parameters, get, retrofit2

I'm using retrofit to make an API call to validate login credentials from server  in android application.

for Example, this is my url : http://example.com/park/app/login.php?username=xyz&password=1234&user_type=1&device_id=12345

I have created Utils class which has URl and constant stuff.

```
public class Utils {
public static final String user_type = "1";
public static final String device_id = "12345";
private static final String LOGIN_URL = "http://example.com/";

public static  ApiServices getServices() {
    return RetroFitClient.getClient(LOGIN_URL).create(ApiServices.class);
}

public class RetroFitClient {
private static Retrofit retroFit = null;

public static Retrofit getClient(String url) {
    return (retroFit == null) ? (new Retrofit.Builder().baseUrl(url)
                    .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory
                            .create()).build()) : retroFit;
}
```

}

Here is Interface:

```
public interface ApiServices {
@GET("park/app/login.php?")
Call<Result> loginUser
        (@Query("username") String username,
         @Query("password") String passwoord,
         @Query("user_type") String user_type,
         @Query("device_id") String device_id);
```

}

When i call the service

```
 private void doLogin(String name, String passwoord, String user_type, String deviceid) {
    Call<Result> call = apiServices.loginUser(name, passwoord, user_type, deviceid);
    call.enqueue(new Callback<Result>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<Result> call, Response<Result> response) {
            Log.e("OnResponse", response.body().getMessage()+" status "+response.body().isStatus());
            if (response.body().isStatus()) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "UserName or Password is incorrect", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
```

I receive the status as false

```
04-25 17:13:20.461 31947-32086/com.example.innobles.velparked D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x71 at 0x000a
04-25 17:13:20.751 31947-31947/com.example.innobles.velparked E/OnResponse: Invalid User. status false
```

where M i doing wrong?
 any Thoughts?

Comment: looks like you are doing all correct. Probably there is something wrong with the data you enter, or with the server.

Comment: @VladyslavMatviienko I'm entering correct data.

Comment: and the code looks correct. Are you sure that if you call the URL from browser, it will work?

Comment: @VladyslavMatviienko yes its working fine when i call the URL From browser.

Comment: @Arshad unable to relate my question to your solution

Comment: @chandmohd I have referred to that solution seeing this error in your error logs "VFY: replacing opcode 0x71 at 0x000a"

Comment: when you passing some user input then used post method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edit following line:

```
@GET("park/app/login.php?")
```

To:

```
@GET("park/app/login")
```

Also check if you are providing valid credentials.
Moreover try passing user_type as an int as follows:

```
@GET("park/app/login.php")
Call<Result> loginUser
    (@Query("username") String username,
     @Query("password") String passwoord,
     @Query("user_type") int user_type,
     @Query("device_id") String device_id);
```